# Tensor product between quaternions and complex numbers.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $H$ be the Hamiltonian quaternions, $\mathbb C$ the complex numbers and $\mathbb R$ the real numbers. Identify $H\otimes_{\mathbb R} 
 \mathbb C$ in familiar terms.

This is an exercise of Modern Algebra of Garrett Birkhoff. I think it may have something to do with the Octonions. Any ideas?

any ideas?

Comment: Well, the octonions aren't associative, so it seems a little unlikely that they'll show up here, as your algebra has dimension $8$ over the reals.

Comment: @pjs36 Since octonions also have dimension 8 over the reals I'm not sure why you're citing that as a reason they're unlikely to show up. The octonions being nonassociative is justification though, since $\mathbb{H}\otimes\mathbb{C}$ is associative.

Comment: Hi @arctictern I wish I could provide insight into why me-from-two-years-ago thought the second part of that sentence was a good idea, but unfortunately, I am as clueless as you are :)

Answer (score 8):

More concretely, this is just $M_2(\mathbb{C})$.

Not sure exactly how Birkhoff wants you to see this, but here's how I did it, using the judo of central simple algebras. $\mathbb{H}$ is a central division algebra (so a CSA) over $\mathbb{R}$. A commonly used fact is that base-extending a CSA gives a CSA, so $\mathbb{H} \mathop{\otimes}\limits_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C}$, viewed as a $\mathbb{C}$ algebra, is a CSA, of the same dimension (4). Another common result is that any CSA over an algebraically closed field is just a matrix algebra over that field, so this is $M_2(\mathbb{C})$.

Answer (score 8):

Since $i$ and $j$ both satisfy $x^2+1$, we should look for matrices that also satisfy this polynomial.  Take $I$ to be the Jordan canonical form and $J$ to be the rational canonical form for $x^2+1$:
$$
I =
\begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt{-1} & 0\\
0 & -\sqrt{-1}
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad
J = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then $JI = -IJ$ as well, so the map
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{H} \otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C} &\to M_2(\mathbb{C})\\
i \otimes 1, j \otimes 1 &\mapsto I,J
\end{align*}
is a homomorphism, and in fact an isomorphism.

Answer (score 5):

The quaternions $\mathbb{H}$ are a right vector space over $\mathbb{C}$.

Then there is an algebra homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{H}\otimes\mathbb{C}\to\mathrm{End}_{\mathbb{C}}(\mathbb{H})$ via

$$\phi(p\otimes z)q=pqz. $$

Using $\{1,\mathbf{j}\}$ as a basis for $\mathbb{H}$ over $\mathbb{C}$ this allows us to identify basis elements of $\mathbb{H}\otimes\mathbb{C}$ with matrices inside $M_2(\mathbb{C})$ in order to check injectivity of $\phi$ hence that it's an isomorphism by dimensions.

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbb{C}\otimes\mathbb{H}$ is isomorphic to the biquaternions or complex quaternions that are similar to $\mathbb{H}$ with complex numbers as scalars. They are a specific feature of Clifford algebra very much useful to reformulate succinctly general relativity.